# jQuery .show(); not working in code, but works in console?

Tags: javascript, jquery

At the beginning of my code (form submission) I want to display a working animated gif and so I have code such as

```
$('form#{$model->formName()}').on('beforeSubmit', function(e){   
    $("#loading").show();
    console.log('1 - spinny thing should be displayed?!');

    var \$form = $(this);
    ...
```

The rest of the code all works and executes just fine, but for some reason, the loading div never displays.

If I enter the exact same line in the console

```
$("#loading").show();
```

it displays.

My CSS for the loading div is

```
#loading {
  z-index: 9999;
  /*center*/
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.loader {
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  border-bottom: 16px solid #3498db;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}
```

also, I used the same approach in multiple other pages and they all work fine.

What should I be looking for?

What am I missing?

Thank you for your time and assistance.

### Update 1

Further testing reveal that is I move the line elsewhere in the function it works, but will not work as the 1st line (unlike every other page in which I have use the code?  Very odd.

### Update 2

I've identified some odd issue with my modal.  I renamed the close button on the modal and suddenly everything works?  I have to do some more digging to understand what is going on.  Thank you all for the help.

Comment: Hard to tell with the code provided. Does your loading div have the correct ID? Is the form perhaps being reloaded due to the submit event, thus re-hiding the loading element? Is the loading element positioned inside a relative element such that it may be appearing off-screen? If you replace that line with `console.log( $("#loading").length )` - what does it log?

Comment: Is the `#loading` element available to the DOM when that code is called? When you run code in your terminal, the page is completely loaded, so it works then, but execution-wise, it might not be.

Comment: So you are saying the console log line(after loading show) works but the loader div don't show? What's the markup in the loading div? Where is the loading div being placed within your form?

Comment: Santi.  It returns 1.

Comment: "So you are saying the console log line(after loading show) works but the loader div don't show?" - Yes, exactly.
The markup is very simple
   <div id="loading" class="loader" style="display: none;"></div>
and is placed after my modal footer (exactly the same as in my other views).

Comment: Why use `beforeSubmit`? Why not only `submit`?

Answer (score 1):

You should try debugger.
Most likely, if the div `#loading` is attached to the DOM at the time this code is executed, the `loading` div should appear. Also, there are fairly likely chances that the div appears for a fraction of seconds and hides due to some code executed below. It is pretty fast and can be missed.
Another possible chance is that you are might be expecting JS to run synchronously.

```
$('form#{$model->formName()}').on('beforeSubmit', function(e){   
    $("#loading").show();
    console.log('1 - spinny thing should be displayed?!');
    debugger;
    var \$form = $(this);
    ...
    ...
    $("#loading").show();
})
```

The `debugger;` statement will pause the execution where ever written and you can see if the div is being loaded or not.
For further reference: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to wrap your code in `$( document ).ready()` to avoid a race condition in which jQuery is attempting to attach an event to a DOM element that does not yet exist. See the jQuery docs: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/